# Why can't I run Gnome apps over remote SSH session?

Tags: ssh, gnome, d-bus

Logging into a remote host using `ssh -X me@host`, I successfully run `gnome-terminal -e "tail -F /var/log/file" &`.  When I log off and then try the same thing the next day, I get this:

> Failed to get the session bus: Failed to connect to socket
>   /tmp/dbus-K99gT9yDjS: Connection refused Falling back to non-factory
>   mode. Failed to summon the GConf demon; exiting.  Failed to contact
>   configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable
>   TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a
>   system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information.
>   (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect
>   to socket /tmp/dbus-K99gT9yDjS: Connection refused)

How do I run gnome-terminal in this situation?

Comment: I don't see a question being asked here. You should do something about that before your post gets closed.

Comment: You might want to cut the 'solution' part out of your question and submit it as an answer. That's acceptable behaviour.

Comment: If you're logging into another machine with SSH, you'll get shell/terminal access. You don't need to open a terminal window on that machine. You can execute commands directly on that machine by typing them into the terminal on your machine.

Comment: As Nigel Nquande says, please press the answer your own question button, and copy and paste your *Solution* section into the answer. Not only is it acceptable, its encouraged.

Comment: In the meantime I have removed the solution from your _question_ since it is not a question. This kind of self-answered question is more than welcome but please post answers as _answers_. Have a look at our [help] or take the 10 second [tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information. You can see the original text (so you don't need to write it out again) in the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/120612/revisions) which you can get to by clicking on the "Edited X min ago" link.

Comment: All, as I submitted in my revision log, I posted my answer to my question within the body of my question because due to my reputation I am unable to post an answer for eight more hours.

Comment: Well . . . !  :-)  I guess I was just thinking it instead of writing it; I don't see my note in the revision log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639261

Which led me to try this:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
$ sudo service messagebus restart
```

Now I can run gnome-terminal!

Comment: Incredibly enough, it worked also in 16.04. I just had to change the restart command to `sudo service dbus restart`. Thanks!

Comment: ⚠️ Warning: restarting dbus will probably restart your entire X session

Answer (score 9):

Indeed when an SSH session is open, it doesn't launch a dbus session. Some programs may launch it, but then the session doesn't know about it (hence can't close it).

Not knowing about the dbus session also means that programs that use dbus but don't launch it themselves will have problems.

dbus sections are per machine and per X11 display.
Their info is stored in $HOME/.dbus/session-bus/-
however, the process referenced there may be closed, so an extra check is needed to determine if launching dbus is needed or not.
Then, the variables there are to be exported to the session.

Then it works like a charm :)

I put the following in my .bash_profile file:

```
# set dbus for remote SSH connections
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" -a -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    machine_id=$(LANGUAGE=C hostnamectl|grep 'Machine ID:'| sed 's/^.*: //')
    x_display=$(echo $DISPLAY|sed 's/^.*:\([0-9]\+\)\(\.[0-9]\+\)*$/\1/')
    dbus_session_file="$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/${machine_id}-${x_display}"
    if [ -r "$dbus_session_file" ]; then
            export $(grep '^DBUS.*=' "$dbus_session_file")
            # check if PID still running, if not launch dbus
            ps $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID | tail -1 | grep dbus-daemon >& /dev/null
            [ "$?" != "0" ] && export $(dbus-launch) >& /dev/null
    else
            export $(dbus-launch) >& /dev/null
    fi
fi
```

notes: hostnamectl is part of systemd and allows to retrieve the machine-id
the dbus-launch displays the variables we want; by using `export $(dbus-launch)` we retrieve the output of dbus-launch and export the variables

Comment: `export $(dbus-launch) >& /dev/null` works for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the previous answers worked in my case but launching the application through dbus-launch did the job:

```
ssh myhost "dbus-launch gnome-terminal --display localhost:10.0 &"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just run:

```
> dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Why would this help?

Comment: This also worked for me.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... just restarting dbus didn't work for me, I had to also remove the machine-id file as well as restart.

```
$ rcdbus stop
$ rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
$ rcdbus start
```

This was on a SLES 11.4 server that I had recently cloned in VMWare. My problem was I could not start yast2 or gedit...

These were the errors I was seeing on the command line:

## yast2

```
** (y2controlcenter-gnome:9981): WARNING **: error accessing /desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_command_line [Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-W7H31tbhVY: Connection refused)]


** (y2controlcenter-gnome:9981): WARNING **:
GError raised: [Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-W7H31tbhVY: Connection refused)]

user_message: [libslab_get_gconf_value: error getting /desktop/gnome/applications/main-menu/lock-down/user_modifiable_apps]
```

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
rm $HOME/.dbus/session-bus/*
```