# cannot launch konsole from xterm

Tags: x11, remote, xterm, konsole, xming

I installed `lxde` & `kde` (along with `konsole`). now I launch `xterm` from a Windows host using `Xlaunch`(`Xming`) which works fine but when I want to launch `konsole`(my preferred shell) I get this error:

```
:~$ konsole
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
unnamed app(4284): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-aGE9cG1V4s: Connection refused" 

unnamed app(4283): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
```

How Can I solve this?

I can launch `startkde` from `Xlaunch` and start `Konsole` within `KDE` just fine, why does it not launch from xterm (without KDE running in the same screen I guess)?

Comment: check this out : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/why-cant-i-run-gnome-apps-over-remote-ssh-session

Comment: Agree - sounds like [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233266/105132) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, it'll work fine if I launch `konsole` with `dbus-launch konsole` like als suggested in this post:[Why can't I run Gnome apps over remote SSH session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/why-cant-i-run-gnome-apps-over-remote-ssh-session)

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same message `Cannot find the D-Bus session server` but for a different reason.

The missing socket it was complaining about was actually being exported from my shell:

```
$ echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-egihF2y0CA,guid=059d8af8243239d92b51c6b55a005504
```

All I had to do was clear that variable (from all my shells) and try again:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment, *[Why can't I run Gnome apps over remote SSH session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/why-cant-i-run-gnome-apps-over-remote-ssh-session)* is a similar issue, similar cause.  When you try to run `konsole`, it attempts to make a connection to the remote D-Bus server, and fails (because that is not running).

As for the warning messages, those are known, and associated with long-term problems in KDE which have apparently not been dealt with (other than suggesting that modifications be made to `konsole` to quiet some of the messages).

Further reading (several of the comments in the bug reports dispute the developers' assertions that the warning can be ignored):

- [QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before...](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=102251) (KDE forum)
- [Bug 297020 - Annoying but harmless warning message on startup of every KUniqueApplication: QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297020)
- [QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde4libs/+bug/959151)