# Forwarding desktop notifications over SSH

Tags: ssh, notifications, xforwarding

I have two computers, a desktop and a laptop, both running Debian Stretch.

Desktop notifications works on the laptop, and I believe it works (the attached 
monitor is broken, so I can't check, and maybe I should say "used to work").

On the laptop I run i3 as wm, no desktop environment, and dunst as notification
daemon.

I have no problems logging in to the desktop using SSH from the laptop. X forwarding also works, but desktop notifications aren't forwarded.

If I run `notify-send "Hello world"` on the laptop, I get a notification saying "Hello world", if I run the same command on the desktop (through a SSH connection, where I can start X programs, so X forwarding is enabled and working) nothing happens. One program that tries to send notifications, outputs:

```
** (transmission-gtk:21556): CRITICAL **: gtr_notify_torrent_completed: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
```

when it tries.

How can I make desktop notifications get forwarded?

Comment: What desktop are you running on the local computer?

Comment: Both are physically local, but on the laptop (and I did so on the desktop too, when the monitor worked) I run i3wm without a DE.

Comment: If what you wanted to know was which notification daemon I have, it's dunst (information also edited into the question).

Comment: As I understand it notifications use *dbus* and you would need to somehow forward those requests. If you google for remote dbus there are some articles that might be appropriate, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188877/119298) answer which might apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, I found 
[Why can't I run Gnome apps over remote SSH session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/why-cant-i-run-gnome-apps-over-remote-ssh-session)

Two of the answers (not the accepted one, but that is older, and might work too, just not be the easiest way any longer) there mentioned `dbus-launch`. And if I run `dbus-launch notify-send "Hello world"`, the notification does appear on the screen of my laptop.